# Why Array list getting block the UI

Tags: android, list, arraylist, kotlin, android-asynctask

I saved the large data from server to array list,I am doing search the list using custom array list like: Arraylist

Normally i did like:
1. Add one Edit text and apply TextWatcher listner to fire filter method.
2. I design one simple filter method and filter some data and pass list to the 
   adapter

I know data is too large but i don't know another method.

My filter method is:

```
 override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String): String {

if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                menu_list_filtered = arrayListOf()
            } else {
                val filteredList = ArrayList<MenuListItem>()
                var i =0
                while (i < menu_list.size  && !isCancelled()) {
                    loge(TAG,"is p canceled "+isCancelled)

                    val arrayList = ArrayList<ProductListItem>()
                    var j =0
                    while (j < 2  && !isCancelled()) {
                        loge(TAG,"is c canceled "+isCancelled)
                        if(menu_list.get(i).product_list!![j].p_name.toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) || menu_list.get(i).product_list!![j].p_desc.toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())){
                            arrayList.add(ProductListItem("","", arrayListOf(), menu_list.get(i).product_list!![j].p_desc,"","", menu_list.get(i).product_list!![j].p_name,"","","","",""))
                            filteredList.add(MenuListItem("","","","", menu_list.get(i).c_name,arrayList))
                        }
                        ++j

                    }
                    ++i

                }
                menu_list_filtered = filteredList
            }
```

}

finally i am passing menu_list_filtered  to adapter and set notifydatasetchanged()

Problem:
When i enter one character on edit text, my UI (focus on edit text) getting stuck a while, I don't know the problem it is getting so much of time 
I tried Asyntask but not resolved.
I know it may be reason of contain list which is so large but i don't know another option.
please suggest me how can i filter(locally) smooth in my project.

Comment: [how to filter recyclerview dataset](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/)

Comment: i have recycler view adapter